# Matlab plot: remove connecting line between disconnected regions?

Tags: matlab, plot

Assume you have 1000 indexed datapoints, with two labels grouped into region1 and region2. Here is an example of how to generate such random data

```
indices = 1:1000;
data = zeros(size(indices));

% some regions of data
region1 = [50:100 200:340 450:500 670:980];
region2 = setdiff(indices, region1);

% generating random data
data(region1) = rand(size(region1)) + 1;
data(region2) = rand(size(region2));
```

Now, if I plot these two regions I get a plot shown below
[image]

The code to generate the plot

```
% plotting
figure(1);
cla(gca);
hold on;
plot(region1, data(region1));
plot(region2, data(region2));
hold off;
```

Now the question: Is there an elegant way of removing the connecting lines between the disconnected data regions, without doing much data manipulation? I still want to use the solid line linestyle, or have a look similar to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you make the x or y values into `NaN` then they wont be plotted. Since you have two complimentary regions, you can use them to set values to `NaN`...

```
% Two vectors which each cover ALL elements in "data", but with NaN where
% the other region is to be plotted. As per example, indices=1:1000;
r1 = 1:1000; r1(region2) = NaN;
r2 = 1:1000; r2(region1) = NaN;
% Plot all data for both lines, but NaNs wont show.
figure(1); clf;
hold on;
plot(r1, data);
plot(r2, data);
hold off;
```

Output:

[image: output]

Comment: Great, this is indeed what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out if you represent regions as a vector of the same length as `x` and `y` with integer values representing the index of the region (e.g. `regions = [1 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 ..]`), there is an elegant one-linear that does the job for an arbitrary number of regions. Here is an example

```
% Generating test data
x = 1:1000;
y = sin(x/100) + rand(1, 1000);
regions = repelem([1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 3], repelem(100, 10)); % a [1 x 1000] vector

% Plotting
plot(bsxfun(@rdivide, x(:), bsxfun(@eq, regions(:), unique(regions(:))')), y(:));
```

Here, I am building the matrix for `x` with values that should not be plotted being `Inf`, due to the `@rdivide` division by `0`. The result is the following.

[image: Region Plotting Example]

I hope this will be helpful for someone in the future.